# Java solving Knights tour takes very long

Tags: java, knights-tour

Hey so i gotta code an algorithm for the Springerproblem (https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/86/Knight%27s_tour.svg)

My code is currently endlessly running at a field of 6x6

We got a Junit class to test it. a field of 3x3 with the starting positions of x=1 and y=1 is working just fine.

```
public class Springerproblem {
    private final int xDelta[] = {1,-1,1,-1,2,-2,2,-2};
    private final int yDelta[] = {2,2,-2,-2,1,1,-1,-1};
    /**
     * Datenstruktur zum Abspeichern der Springerzuege
     */
    private int[][] springerFeld;
    private int n0;
    /**
     * Gibt ein zweidimensionales, quadratisches int-Array zurueck. 
     * n ist die Schachbrettbreite.
     * Der Springer startet an Position (x,y) mit 0<=x,y<n.
     * Auf den jeweiligen Postionen des Arrays sind die Positionen des 
     * Springers eingetragen. Die erste Position traegt die 1.
     * Wenn sich das Problem nicht loesen laesst, so wird eine 
     * NoSolutionException geworfen.
     */
    public int[][] springer(int n, int x, int y) throws NoSolutionException{
        springerFeld = new int[n][n]; //erzeuge neues Spielfeld
        this.n0 = n; // übernehme n

        if (spring(x, y, 1)) { //rekursionsende wird im Stack als letztes abgebaut zugNr ist dabei 1 also die Startposition
            return springerFeld;
        }
        else {
            throw new NoSolutionException();
        }
    }

    private boolean spring(int x, int y, int zugnummer) {
         springerFeld[x][y] = zugnummer;//Zugnummer ist am Anfang 1
        if(zugnummer == n0*n0) { //dann ist es am Zeil und teilt methode springer mit dass es fertig ist
            return true;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < xDelta.length; i++) {
            int newX = x + xDelta[i]; //neue Position x
            int newY = y + yDelta[i]; // neue Position y
            if(loesbar(newX, newY, zugnummer+1)) { // wenn die nächste Position frei ist 
                springerFeld[newX][newY] = zugnummer+1; // füge sie zum weg hinzu
                if(spring(newX, newY, zugnummer+1)) { //rekursionsaufruf mit der nächsten Position
                    return true;
                }
                 // backtracking
            }  
        }
        springerFeld[x][y] = 0;
        return false;
    }

    private boolean loesbar(int x, int y, int zugnummer) {       
        if(0 <= x && x < n0 && 0 <= y && y< n0 && springerFeld[x][y] == 0 && spring(x, y, zugnummer+1)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

**Also the method names etc. cannot be changed**

Comment: You did not ask a question. The algorithm is for recursive depth first search, which can run for a long time.  If you think there is a bug, add debugging output.

Comment: im quite new so i dont really know how to do it.. im just asking for help..

Comment: To get help on this site, it's best to read how to use this site first. Consider reading these first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822, https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166. Your question should include the steps you did yourself for debugging, and much more details on where you are stuck.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20783702/knights-tour-baktracking-lasts-too-long

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is correct. But your `loesbar()` method should not call `spring(...)`, else your algorithm spends twice the time each step.

Also the sequence of steps to try is not optimal for finding a single solution.
This question had the same issue: [Knights tour backtracking lasts too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20783702/knights-tour-baktracking-lasts-too-long)

Using a different sequence of steps finds a first solution more quickly:

```
    private final int xDelta[] = { 2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1, 1, 2 };
    private final int yDelta[] = { 1, 2, 2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1 };
```

An explanation is given here: [Knight's tour backtrack implementation choosing the step array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21511683)